# bootstrap panel with button - collapse issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix" role="tab" id="heading-details" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details" data-parent="#panel-group" href="#details">
       <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">My panel title</h4>

       <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" asp-action="Action">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="details" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.Partial("_DetailsPartial", Model)                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Issue:**

When I click on a button link then panel body expands/collapses. I don't want to toggle panel body when clicking on button.

How can I turn off data-toggle on the button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I've done:

- Added class "disable-collapse" to the button
- Added script below

```js
$('.disable-collapse').click(function (e) 
{ event.stopPropagation(); })
```

With this, panel body toggles when I click on the panel header but not when i click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

Why don,t you remove the `data-toggle="collapse"` from inside your

```
 <div class="panel-heading clearfix" role="tab" id="heading-details" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details" data-parent="#panel-group" href="#details">
```

It will automatically prevent the collapse

or use  `stopPropagation();`  method which will do the same

it will be something like below.Add an Id into your link button .

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" id="btn" asp-action="Action">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</a>
```

> Jquery Code

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

Comment: but i need to fire button onclick function. is it disable ??

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="panel-body">
        @Html.Partial("_DetailsPartial", Model)                
    </div>
```

Remove this piece of code

Comment: But I want my Panel body to expand/collapse. I need to turn it off when pressing the button link.